# Let $X,Y$ topological vectorial spaces and $T: X \rightarrow Y$ invertible.Prove that if $T$ is linear then $T^{-1}$ is linear

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X,Y$ topological vectorial spaces and $T: X \rightarrow Y$ invertible.I want prove that if $T$ is linear then $T^{-1}$ is linear.

My proof:

We know that $T$ is linear and invertible i.e. exist $T^{-1}: Y \rightarrow X$ so that $T^{-1} \circ T= id_X$

Given $v'$,$w' \in Y$ because $T$ is invertible exist $v,w \in X$ so that $v'=T(v),w'=T(w)$.

$T^{-1}(v'+w')=T^{-1}(T(v)+T(w))=T^{-1}(T(v+w))=v+w=T^{-1}(v)+T^{-1}(w)$. (additivity)

Let $k \in R$: $T^{-1}(kv')=T^{-1}(kT(v))=T^{-1}(T(kv))=kv=kT^{-1}(v')$

Comment: Do you mean "topological spaces" or "vector spaces"?

Comment: the prof said topological vectorial spaces

Comment: @GiuliaB. Then why did you not put that in your question?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected the text.Now is it right?